# What is the difference between HP iLO Free version and Advanced Version?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ilo

I have the HP iLO Advanced 3 year warranty that is expiring in 7 months. I wanted to know is it worth staying with the advanced pacakge, or can I do the same exact thing with the free version of iLO.

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: "Check with your vendor" - HP's website has a lot of information the explains the differences and "why" you should use the paid-for version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This site has a table with the differences: http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/servers/ilo/licenses.html

You can't do the same thing with free however its a onetime purchase, warranty is just for  support.

Answer (score 6):

Don't do anything. You've entered an ILO license key, so your server and ILO will continue operating with the ILO Advanced functionality. The warranty is just paper support.

To answer your question, though, the main difference between the ILO Advanced and unlicensed ILO is that the Advanced license can use remote console and remote media functions. That feature is limited in the free edition.

Comment: Ok thats fine. Once I looked at Jim's chart link, the only thing we really need is the power managment, which is a basic feature. However if it will still have iLO Advanced functionality even after the warranty lapes, that's even better.

Answer (score 0):

This is the report on the different features between iLO standard and iLO advanced for Proliant servers Generation 8,9 and 10. https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=c04952001